# Error on Rendering a View to a String

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to render a view to a string in ASP Net Core 1 but keep receiving the error:

> Operator '!' cannot be applied to operand of type ''

on this line:

> view.RenderAsync(viewContext).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

I am confused as to why this might be the case and looking for some assistance.
Alot of the examples and help I have seen in this area relate to RC1. We are using the final core 1.0 here.

I'm using the following code which i found online:

```
    public ViewRender(
        IRazorViewEngine viewEngine,
        ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider,
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _viewEngine = viewEngine;
        _tempDataProvider = tempDataProvider;
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }


    public string Render<TModel>(string name, TModel model, ActionContext actionContext)
    {

        var viewEngineResult = _viewEngine.FindView(actionContext, name, true);

        if (!viewEngineResult.Success)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Couldn't find view '{0}'", name));
        }

        var view = viewEngineResult.View;

        using (var output = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(
                actionContext,
                view,
                new ViewDataDictionary<TModel>(
                    metadataProvider: new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(),
                    modelState: new ModelStateDictionary())
                {
                    Model = model
                },
                new TempDataDictionary(
                    actionContext.HttpContext,
                    _tempDataProvider),
                output,
                new HtmlHelperOptions());

            view.RenderAsync(viewContext).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            return output.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't stuff tags into the question title. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging on how to correctly use tags. Also, please don't use [tag:asp.net] and [tag:asp.net-mvc] for ASP.NET Core related questions. The correct tags are [tag:asp.net-core] and [tag:asp.net-core-mvc]

Comment: ok no problem, thank you for your help.. Have a nice day